# macOSアプリをフルスクリーンしていて現在の入力ソースを知る方法

Tags: macos, ime

MacOS でブラウザやVSCodeなどをフルスクリーン表示で使用しているとメニューバーが隠れているため入力ソース（言語や入力モード）が分からないです。

[image: メニューバーの input source]

入力ソースを画面の隅に表示したり、切り替えたタイミングだけ（Windowsみたいに）表示したり、入力ソースが分かるようにする何らかの方法はないでしょうか。

環境

- macOS Big Sur
- MacBook Pro, USキーボード, タッチバーは付いていない
- 主に日本語（ローマ字入力）と英語 (Dvorak) を切り替えたい

Answer (score 1):

入力ソース切り替えのショートカットキーを押した際に、モディファイアキーを長押しすると次に選択される入力ソースが画面のほぼ中央に出ますが、これでは不足でしょうか？

Comment: 「前の入力ソースを選択」のショートカット長押しですね… ありがとうございます。使ってみます。

Answer (score 1):

ちなみに、Montereyではフルスクリーンでもメニューバーを表示できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]